# when using quartz shcheduler i came accross with NoClassDefFoundErroe

Tags: java, spring, jsp, quartz-scheduler

```
public void  HelloSchedule()throws Exception{

      SchedulerFactory sf=new StdSchedulerFactory();
      Scheduler sched=sf.getScheduler();
      sched.start();
      JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(Quartzjob.class)
                .withIdentity("job1", "group1").build();

        Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
                .withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withIntervalInSeconds(20)
                    .repeatForever()).startNow().build();

        sched.scheduleJob(job, trigger);

      }
```

**Exception**

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory at       org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.<init>(StdSchedulerFactory.java:274)
at quartzSheduler.QuartzTrigger.HelloSchedule(QuartzTrigger.java:28)v
```

i am getting the exception, i have used Quarta-2.1.5.jar , whether i shoud use transaction librarys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be missing the [SL4J](http://www.slf4j.org/) library. You can avoid such dependency errors by using maven and importing the dependency from a [repo](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz/1.7.3). You need a maven project to link to the quartz dependency.

Comment: thank you very much...i was able to execute after using SL4j library

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you add slf4j-api jar in your application or in server lib directory.